# Libs which need "new ..." in vue.js - eslint is bragging about the spelling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, swiper.js

What is the best/correct way to use Vue libs (for example a Swiper) which need a 'new ...' in the script part? 'new ...' works fine in the frontend, but ESlint is bragging about it no matter how i write it:

```
const swiper = new Swiper > 'swiper' is assigned a value but never used ...
new Swiper > Do not use 'new' for side effects
Without new > Class constructor Swiper cannot be invoked without 'new' and not working anymore in the frontend
```

So, what is the "correct" way to write this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EsLint - Suppress "Do not use 'new' for side effects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33287045/eslint-suppress-do-not-use-new-for-side-effects)

Comment: Related, yes, but i think a little bit different. I've seen that, but i don't think this is the "best practise" or is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i was able to talk to a "vue.js veteran" and he told me that there isn't a "best practise". The way he fixes this in his apps is by writing a

```
/* eslint-disable no-new */
```

right before the new ... part or even disable it globally in the eslint.js